# Why is my UpTimeRobot monitor not working? It says that there was a connection timeout

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, monitoring

today, my monitor for my discord bot stopped working, it was based on uptimerobot's free auto pinging feature that made my discord bot refresh every 5 minutes, thus keeping it on. Today, that all stopped working, and my monitor has been down for the whole day, and so has my discord bot, I've tried everything from resetting the monitor to making a whole new account to try to fix it, and nothing has worked. Is there an issue with my code? By the way, every time I try something new to fix it, it just says that my monitor is down, and that the connection timed out, anyways here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Greetings. I am currently alive!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()

also yes I have all the correct imports
```

Comment: There could be many things here. First do you have the ```keep_alive()``` function at the end of your code in the main file before the token? Edit : Uptime Robot was down for about 2 hours

Comment: I have the keep alive function at the end, but let me check uptimerobot

Comment: @ChaoticNebula It's still down

Comment: Restart your monitor

Comment: @ChaoticNebula I tried that

Comment: @ChaoticNebula it's working now

Comment: Cool, uptime robot had a downtime, my bots hosted on it were down too

Answer (score 0):

-make sure the website can be seen by outside traffic
-use something like replit if you want a eazy way to host it
-make sure to put it above client.run("token")

-from head dev of rage bots